# Is Blazor still an experimental?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

We think to use blazor framework to build an eCommerce project, and I [read a Visual Studio Magazine article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/03/08/blazor-0-9-0.aspx?m=1) that blazor is an an experimental project so is it still under developing until now? and it's stable to use it in real application?

Comment: check this  [link](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/03/08/blazor-0-9-0.aspx?m=1)

Comment: The way to go is to look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#blazor-webassembly): `Blazor Server is supported in ASP.NET Core 3.0` vs `Blazor WebAssembly is in preview.`

Comment: Microsoft announce .NET Core 3 last month

Answer (score 1):

The WebAssembly Blazor is still expiremental and would be shipped in the beginning of 2020.

Server-Side Blazor is RTM and Microsoft consider that production technology.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.0